# A good rules engine for asp.net-mvc applications

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, rule-engine

I looking for a good Rules Engine to work with in my asp.net-mvc applications.

What **good** options do I have?

Comment: As far as I know, the only MVC business rules engine is  http://rule.codeeffects.com

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [Windows Workflow Foundation Rules Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480193.aspx). It can be used without actually using the rest of Workflow Foundation.